# Error when using async/await controller function in express route

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I try to add controllers to my project, but can't adapt my async/await syntax.

My NodeJs/Express project has the following structure:

```
controllers/
  categories.js
models/
  category.js
routes/
  categoryRoutes.js
services/
  db.js
app.js
package.json
```

categoryRoutes.js **Route**:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Controlller
const CategoryController = require('../controllers/categories');

router.post('/get-all', CategoryController.getAll); // This is where the app fails
```

categories.js **Controller**:

```
// Model
const Category = require('../models/category');

exports.getAllCategories = async (req, res, next) => {
    const result = await Category.getAll();
    next();
}
```

category.js **Model**:

```
var db = require('../services/db');

exports.getAll = async () => {
    const categories = await db.get().query('SELECT * FROM categories');
    next(null, categories);
}
```

The code produces the following error inside the categoryRoutes.js File:

```
 **\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
[0]         throw new Error(msg);
[0]         ^
[0]
[0] Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
[0]     at Route.(anonymous function) [as post] (**\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
[0]     at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as post] (**\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (**\routes\categoryRoutes.js:53:8)
[0]     at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
[0]     at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
[0]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
[0]     at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
[0]     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (**\app.js:126:24)
[0]     at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
[0]     at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
[0]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

What's the right way of using **Async/Await** Controller/Model functions inside Router.get/post... ?

Comment: `router.post` expects a function not a `promise`

Comment: Possibly just a typo / mismatched name? `getAll` in categoryRoutes.js (route) vs. `getAllCategories` in categories.js (controller).

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLonowski in fact there had been a typo!